# GTX 1070 and Triple monitor solution

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have upgraded to a GTX 1070 and nothing is working right for me. previously I had a 980 running triple monitors but after this upgrade only one monitor will boot and I cannot download any type of driver for the card without a login loop happening. I have gone into BIOS and switched to PCIE for monitor detection but every time I do this I get the same login loop as well. I have reinstalled Linux twice with no success and windows is working just fine.

I am quite new to Linux if you haven't already figured out, any help would be much appreciated.